# Textarea caret position

Tags: javascript, textarea, caret

I found this Fiddle and edited it. 
At current on any keypress the div on left side of textarea appears ( gray color div ) at caret position where the text is written.

I want the div to appear on Keypress of Enter next to caret position everytime `( get the caret position and show div next to it on enter press )` and if any other key press disappear the div.

I'm bit confused how the keypress used here in this code.

here : http://jsfiddle.net/eMwKd/30/